# Different email addresses of same email server for sending and receiving

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am actually a fresher in terms of configuring an email server.
Recently I configured a Postfix email server combining with dovecot and squirrelmail on AWS EC2 centos server, following this guide:

[How to configure an email server](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-an-email-server-on-centos7/)

The problem I am facing is that, when I send an email using the mail server that I have configured on external emails like outlook, gmail etc. is sent using the following email address

noreply@example.app.

But, I cannot send an email to the above-mentioned address using outlook or gmail because the sender shows me this error:
[Gmail Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVogG.png)

**But once I send the email after modifying the above-mentioned email address to the following:
noreply@mail.example.app**,
I receive an email on my configured email server.
What I want is that both the sender and receiver email addresses should be:
noreply@example.app
Here are my DNS records for the domain:
[DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnSBE.png)

Below is my Postfix Master.cf File:
'''

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
587      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
```

Below is my Postfix Main.cf

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix

mail_owner = postfix

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

debug_peer_level = 2

debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no

manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
myhostname = mail.example.app
mydomain = example.app
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
relay_domains = $mydestination
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a DNS issue. You have a wrong a MX record, i.e. your domain **example.app** doensn't have an MX record (**mail.example.app** has an MX record instead, but it doesn't need it). Thus Gmail tries to direct mail to A record (as a fallback).

Add into `example.app` zone the following record:

`example.app. MX 10 mail.example.app.`

(and remove the `mail.example.app MX`, it does no harm, but it doesn't needed)

this will tell the world that mail for **example.app** domain is processed at mail.example.app and after obvious negative DNS caching timeout Gmail and others will deliver mail to your mail server.

Comment: Hi,
I updated my DNS records to:
https://imgur.com/FgEfJbf